# Entity Framework 6: Include nested nullable many to many children

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

My include is always empty. Although I can see in the SQL database there are links between parent and children.

```
IQueryable<ManageProductItems> models = db.Products
    .Include(m => m.Collections).Include(m => m.Images)
    .Include(m => m.VariantDetails.Select(x => x.Variants.Select(z => z.VariantType)))
    .Select....
```

I want to include nested `Products -> VariantDetails -> Variants -> VariantType`

The result always gives me `Variants = null`.

Here is the model configuration:

```
public class Product
{
    ...
    public ICollection<ProductCollection> Collections { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductVariantDetail> VariantDetails { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductImage> Images { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductVariantType> ProductVariantTypes { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductVariant> ProductVariants { get; set; }
}

public class ProductVariantDetail
{
    ....
    public ICollection<ProductVariant> Variants { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    [CascadeDelete]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductImage ProductImage { get; set; }
}

public class ProductVariant
{
    ...
    [ForeignKey("VariantType")]
    public Guid VariantTypeId { get; set; }

    [CascadeDelete]
    public virtual ProductVariantType VariantType { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductVariantDetail> VariantDetails { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public Guid? ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class ProductVariantType
{
    ...
    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public Guid? ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

There is `dbo.ProductVariantDetailProductVariants` table in the SQL server which map `ProductVariantDetail` and `ProductVariant`. The mapped ids from both tables are correct.

But this happens:

`Products -> VariantDetails -> Variants = null`

---

### EDIT 1

I tried to just shorten the query with:

`var xxx = db.ProductVariantDetails.Include(m => m.Variants).ToList();`

The variants get loaded correctly. So I am sure that there is a problem with nested include or a bug.

---

### EDIT 2

This is so weird. So I tried to play with the code. I put this:

```
var xxx = db.ProductVariantDetails.Include(m => m.Variants.Select(z => z.VariantType)).ToList();

IQueryable<ManageProductItems> models = db.Products
    .Include(m => m.Collections).Include(m => m.Images)
    .Include(m => m.VariantDetails.Select(x => x.Variants.Select(z => z.VariantType)))
    .Select....
```

So the `xxx` cache the `VariantType` then when `models` query the whole entities, `Product -> VariantDetails -> Variants -> VariantType` get loaded correctly. If I just query `models` without `xxx`, the problem still persist.

So somehow the `db` needs to cache the `Variants` and `VariantTypes` before that.

How can I solve this?

Comment: use this one `db.Products.Include(x => x.VariantDetails).ThenInclude(v => v.Variants )`

Comment: `ThenInclude()` is only available for EF Core

Comment: A little bit off-topic: Are you sure, you want to select als columns from all the tables you mentioned? Wouldn't using _JOINS_ and _SELECT_ the columns you need be more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This is a second answer which addresses a secondary issue in your code. First read the other answer as I suspect this will be the most direct answer to your question.*

Your `Select` is undoing/ignoring your `Include`. `Include` is (explicitly) used to implicitly and automatically fetch related entities, but `Select` explicitly asks for a different return value, which overrides the implicit inclusion rules you set up.

Some examples to showcase how it works:

```
var list = db.Products
             .ToList();
```

This returns a list of products with no related entities loaded.

```
var list = db.Products
             .Include(m => m.ProductOwner)
             .ToList();
```

This returns a list of products with the `ProductOwner` property also loaded.

```
var list = db.Products
             .Select(p => p.Name)
             .ToList();

var list2 = db.Products
             .Include(m => m.ProductOwner)
             .Select(p => p.Name)
             .ToList();
```

Both lists are a list of strings (with the product names). Doing the `Include` was irrelevant.

```
var list = db.Products
             .Select(p => p.ProductOwner.Name)
             .ToList();

var list2 = db.Products
             .Include(m => m.ProductOwner)
             .Select(p => p.ProductOwner.Name)
             .ToList();
```

Both lists are a list of strings (with the productowner names). Doing the `Include` was irrelevant.

This is an important part to notice: **you did not need the `Include` to fetch the name of the related `ProductOwner` entity**. This is because your `Select` statement explicitly asked EF to fetch the related entity data, and therefore EF did not need an `Include`, because it didn't need to implicitly load related entities anyway.

This behavior is maintained for any `Select` statement, including those where you still use the full `Product` entity. Which means:

```
var list = db.Products
             .Select(p => new { Product = p })
             .ToList();

var list2 = db.Products
             .Include(m => m.ProductOwner)
             .Select(p => new { Product = p })
             .ToList();
```

In both cases, you will get the `Product` entity **without** its related `ProductOwner`, because EF listens to the `Select` and ignores any other instructions about what data to load (including `Include`).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an include:

```
db.Products
  .Include(m => m.Collections)
  .Include(m => m.Images)
  .Include(m => m.VariantDetails.Select(x => x.Variants.Select(z => z.VariantType)))
  .Select(...);
```

You never asked for the `Variants` themselves to be loaded. When the `Variants` aren't loaded, all subsequently related entities are ignored.

Try the following:

```
db.Products
  .Include(m => m.Collections)
  .Include(m => m.Images)
  .Include(m => m.VariantDetails.Select(x => x.Variants))
  .Include(m => m.VariantDetails.Select(x => x.Variants.Select(z => z.VariantType)))
  .Select(...);
```

However, there may be a secondary issue which you've hidden by obscuring the `Select` statement. I added a second answer to address this potential secondary issue.

Comment: If you read the official documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data it is said using include(select()) will load everything from parent to children tho.

Comment: @AlvinStefanus: My experience with this has been different in the past, though this may have been in older EF versions, I can't be sure.

Comment: @Flater FYI you don't need `.Include(m => m.VariantDetails.Select(x => x.Variants))` when you have the subsequent include going another level deeper.